# How to modify Mongo values in where-clause in query?

Tags: php, where-clause, mongodb

Is there any way to modify the mongo values in a where-clause in a find query?

This is the one I use right now:

```
$db->users->findOne(array("redirect_uri" => $arrParsedUrl['host']));
```

- In this case I need to make sure that the value earlier inserted into the database is only the host part of the URL.

What I would like to do is someting like this (but it's not working):

```
$db->users->findOne(array(parse_url("redirect_uri")['host'] => $arrParsedUrl['host']));
```

- In this case I would be able to insert the complete URL in the database from the beginning. The "parse_url" function in the query makes sure that only the host part is actually compared.

Any ideas how to achive something similar?

Edit: 
I don't want to update the values in the database. Only modify the value from the database used in the where-clause that is compared to the input value.

The input value will always be the host part of an URL.

Edit2:

1. I have several documents in a collection called users.
2. All documents have a field called "redirect_uri" that contains an URL.
3. When I call a php function with an url as input I would like to return the document where the host part of the input URL is the same as the host part of the "redirect_uri" in the document. 
   E.g. http://www.foo.com/bananas ("redirect_url") = http://www.foo.com/apples (input URL)
4. How can I query MongoDB to get the document where the host part of the "redirect_url" is the same as the  host part of the input URL? To modify the input URL to www.foo.com is not a problem but how do I modify the "redirect_url" part in the same way to make the query give me a correct answer?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't understand your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, you are either looking for [update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) (this one just updates):

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi );
```

or [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) (this one updates and retrieves)

Edit:

Just do the transformation on the client side. The mongoDB philosophy is to push as much work to the clients as possible.e

Edit2:

- You can use [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php).
- You can restructure your database to store the host in a separate field.

Comment: So it's not possible to modify the value from the database in the where-clause?

Comment: Uhm.. it would be better if you told us what you're trying to achieve. Yeah, I see you provided an example but I don't understand a word from it.

Comment: Great. Regular expressions seems to be able to handle this case the way I want to. Thanks.