# MongoDB - PHP modifying array's object values

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel-4

I have a field which stores an array of objects. I want to modify the object's "status" value depending on the "id" value the object possesses.

```
"authors" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "18",
            "first_name" : "Buddhika",
            "last_name" : "Chathuranga",
            "$$hashKey" : "object:35",
            "status" : NumberLong(0)
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3", // search for this number
            "first_name" : "Pasindu",
            "last_name" : "Priyanath",
            "$$hashKey" : "object:43",
            "status" : NumberLong(0) // modify this to 1
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage positional update in MongoDB to update values inside array.

[Mongo Positional Update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Please find script below.

```
db.authors.update(
{"authors.id": "3"},
{ $set: { "authors.$.status" : NumberLong(1) }} 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update in Mongo DB php:

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi );
```

[Detail Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923962/how-to-modify-mongo-values-in-where-clause-in-query)